# Ruby - Is there a way to overwrite the __FILE__ variable?

Tags: ruby, global-variables

I'm doing some unit testing, and some of the code is checking to see if files exist based on the relative path of the currently-executing script by using the **FILE** variable.  I'm doing something like this:

```
if File.directory?(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__),'..','..','directory'))
    blah blah blah ...
else
    raise "Can't find directory"
end
```

I'm trying to find a way to make it fail in the unit tests without doing anything drastic.  Being able to overwrite the __ FILE __ variable would be easiest, but as far as I can tell, it's impossible.

Any tips?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My tip? Refactor!

Comment: Hahaha, yeah, I thought about that.  I was hoping there was some little ruby gem hidden somewhere (no pun intended, and no, not a rubygem)

:)

Comment: @Markus Orreley: Glad you're taking it lightly. I do hate it when low-level code is making decisions for itself like this. Unit test provide a great excuse to fix that.

Comment: I did figure out how to do it, but I think yours is the real answer.  I'll put it down below as another possible answer though

Answer (score 1):

I didn't mark this as the real answer, since refactoring would be the best way to go about doing it.  However, I did get it to work:

```
wd = Dir.getwd
# moves us up two directories, also assuming Dir.getwd
# returns a path of the form /folder/folder2/folder3/folder4...
Dir.chdir(wd.scan(/\/.*?(?=[\/]|$)/)[0..-3].join)
...run tests...
Dir.chdir(wd)
```

I had tried to do it using Dir.chdir('../../'), but when I changed back, File.expand_path(File.dirname(__ FILE __)) resolved to something different than what it was originally.

Answer (score 1):

Programming Ruby 1.9 says on page 330 that `__FILE__` is read only. It also describes it as a "execution environment variable".

However, you can [define](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496102/what-does-class-eval-end-eval-file-line-mean-in-ruby) `__FILE__` within an instance_eval. I don't think that'd help with your problem.