# What does class_eval <<-"end_eval", __FILE__, __LINE__ mean in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I'm learning how to use class_eval in modules (I'm somewhat familiar with class_eval) and came across [this helpful class in resource_controller](http://github.com/jamesgolick/resource_controller/blob/master/lib/resource_controller/accessors.rb).  In there they have things like this:

```
class_eval <<-"end_eval", __FILE__, __LINE__

  def #{block_accessor}(*args, &block)
    unless args.empty? && block.nil?
      args.push block if block_given?
      @#{block_accessor} = [args].flatten
    end

    @#{block_accessor}
  end

end_eval
```

What does `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` do in that context?  I know `__FILE__` references the current file, but what does that whole thing do exactly?  Don't really know how to search for that :).

Answer (score 59, accepted):

`__FILE__` and `__LINE__` are sort of dynamic constants that hold the file and line that are currently executing.  Passing them in here allow errors to properly report their location.

```
instance_eval <<-end_eval, __FILE__, __LINE__
  def foo
    a = 123
    b = :abc
    a.send b
  end
end_eval

foo
```

When you run this

```
$ ruby foo.rb 
foo.rb:5:in `send': undefined method `abc' for 123:Fixnum (NoMethodError)
    from foo.rb:5:in `foo'
    from foo.rb:11
```

Note it says the file and line #5 even though that was just text in an eval.  Without those the file/line trick the output would look like this:

```
$ ruby foo.rb 
(eval):5:in `send': undefined method `abc' for 123:Fixnum (NoMethodError)
    from (eval):5:in `foo'
    from foo.rb:11
```

The stack trace simply shows `(eval)` which isn't as helpful.

Comment: It might be good to mention that using `define_method` instead won't need this kind of tricks, plus it won't open vulnerabilities (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003328/how-do-i-use-class-eval/3003509#3003509)

Answer (score 4):

The `<<` is the start of a [heredoc](http://docs.huihoo.com/ruby/ruby-man-1.4/syntax.html#here_doc). That line is the start of a multiline string. The string is evaled to create the function. The [class_eval](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Module.html#M001650) function uses the __FILE__ and __LINE__ to add debug information.

Comment: But but but...aren't you the golfing wizard from anarchy golf? You should know Ruby like the back of your hand! :-D (That was a comment on the wishy-washiness of your statement about what `class_eval`'s behaviour is. If your intent wasn't to sound uncertain, I take my comment back.)

Comment: Haha... I never needed that function because it was too many characters.

Comment: In your case it adds the filename and line number before error messages. Look at the example in the link: http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Module.html#M001650

Answer (score 2):

Let's also note, that `eval`-ling strings should be avoided where possible. In your particular case, replacing `#class_eval` with `#class_exec` is possible, and should be preferred:

```
class_exec do
  define_method block_accessor do |*args, &block|
    unless args.empty? && block.nil?
      args.push block if block_given?
      instance_variable_set "@#{block_accessor}", [args].flatten
    end
    instance_variable_get "@#{block_accessor}"
  end
end
```