# How do I use class_eval?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I don't understand `class_eval`.

```
class Module
  def attr_ (*syms)
    syms.each do |sym|
      class_eval %{def #{sym}= (val)
        @#{sym} = val
      end}
    end
  end
end
```

What does the `%` mean?

What does `class_eval` do?

And where is `(val)` coming from?

Comment: I copied your pastebin directly (and fixed the writing). I presume the last `}` is misplaced though; it should be after `val`, not after `end`

Comment: You shouldn't leave a space between a method identifier and the parens that follow. Ruby will warn you when you do.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The short answer is: you probably want to *avoid* using `class_eval` like this.

Here's an explanation of your code:

The `%{hello}` is just another way to write a string literal in Ruby, without having to worry about escaping double or single quotes within the string:

```
%{hello "world"} == "hello \"world\""  # => true
```

The `val` in your code is an argument of the method being defined.

The `class_eval` is used to define some methods by computing the text one would write to do the definition and then evaluating it. It is not necessary here, BTW. An equivalent code would be:

```
class Module
  def attr_ (*syms)
    syms.each do |sym|
      define_method "#{sym}=" do |val|
        instance_variable_set "@#{sym}", val
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This is just equivalent to the builtin `attr_writer`.

**Update**: There can actually be a significant difference between the two...

The `class_eval` version is vulnerable if you can't trust the argument `syms`. For example:

```
class Foo
  attr_ "x; end; puts 'I can execute anything here!'; val=42; begin; val"
end
```

The `class_eval` version will print "I can execute anything here" twice, proving it can execute anything. The `define_method` version won't print anything.

This [type of code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/f1d8f2af72e21d41efd02488f1c2dcf829e17783/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb#L188-200) was pivotal to create [major vulnerability](http://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/detail?vulnId=CVE-2013-0333) for all installed Rails apps.

Comment: what does the word evaluate mean? i dont get that word.

Comment: In this context, execute some instructions.

If you were to "evaluate" the expression 6 + 5, it's 11.