# "Here methods" in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, heredoc

I'm writing a few helpers to DRY up my tests. I pictured something like:

```
class ActiveSupport::TestCase

  def self.test_presence_validation_of model, attribute
    test "should not save #{model.to_s} with null #{attribute.to_s}", <<-"EOM"
      #{model.to_s} = Factory.build #{model.to_sym}, #{attribute.to_sym} => nil
      assert !#{model.to_s}.save, '#{model.to_s.capitalize} with null #{attribute.to_s} saved to the Database'
    EOM
    # Another one for blank attribute.
  end
end
```

So that this:

```
class MemberTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase

  test_presence_validation_of :member, :name
end
```

Executes exactly this at `MemberTest` class scope:

```
test 'should not save member with null name' do
  member = Factory.build :member, :name => nil
  assert !member.save, 'Member with null name saved to the Database'
end
```

Is it possible to do it this way (with a few adaptations, of course; I doubt my "picture" works), or do I have to use `class_eval`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you seen Shoulda? It's great for testing common Rails functionality such as validations, relationships etc. https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers

Comment: Accepting your answer, since I ended up using Shoulda after all.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, it seems `class_eval` is necessary since I want to interpolate variable names into actual code.

[Illustrated here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496102/what-does-class-eval-end-eval-file-line-mean-in-ruby)