# Getting current line of code in Ruby

Tags: ruby, logging, call

Crazy thought today.

Is there any way to grab the line number that code has been executed on?

```
Logger.info "I was run on line #{get_line_number}"
```

Comment: Not crazy. Useful when handling exceptions.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use `__LINE__` variable. See this https://stackoverflow.com/a/2496240/100466 answer also.