# Ruby class_eval do vs <<-M or <<-READER

Tags: ruby

I normally use class_eval do with the block but also saw examples like follows, Im trying to understand in what scenario I should use them, specifically <<-READER and <<-M

```
class_eval <<-READER, __FILE__ , __LINE__ + 1
  def #{sym}
    @#{sym}
  end
READER
```

OR

```
class_eval <<-M, __FILE__ , __LINE__ + 1
  def m
  end
M
```

Comment: What part of this are you asking about? The HEREDOC style `<<` or the use of `class_eval` in general?

Comment: Hi @tadman do block vs <<-READER and  <<-M

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does class\_eval <<-"end\_eval", \_\_FILE\_\_, \_\_LINE\_\_ mean in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496102/what-does-class-eval-end-eval-file-line-mean-in-ruby)

Comment: `eval` takes either a string or a block of code via `do ... end` or `{ ... }`. The string version can be specified any way a string can, including HEREDOC.